# Descriptive message services

Tags: debian, systemd

I have Debian 8 jessie installed on my Laptop, before when I had a Debian 7 wheezy, the system startup and shutdown showing descriptive messages such as these:

[image]

Now on debian 8 jessie, when I start the system only see this:

[image]

Sometimes it displays messages as to wheezy. But in 95% displays as above.

When I restarting the services does not show me the messages successfully:

[image]

As I can make my Debian 8 to be more descriptive when my system startup|shutdown and when start|stop|restart the services.

Is this related to systemd?

Comment: For the first two images, remove `quiet` from the bootloader options (`/etc/default/grub` followed by `update-grub` command). The later isn't typical. Do you get output if you do `systemctl restart apache2` instead?

Comment: @jordanm with `sudo systemctl restart apache2` show the same output :(

Comment: To check the status of a service in systemd you use `systemctl status <serviceName>` otherwise you're meant to infer from the lack of output that it was successful. If service start up had failed it would tell you to check `journalctl -xn` for a description of why.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is related to systemd. You can attain more verbose boot logging by one of these methods:

- add `systemd.show_status=1` to the kernel cmdline;
- set `ShowStatus=yes` in `/etc/systemd/system.conf`;
- remove `quiet` from the kernel cmdline.

Ref.: [systemd(1)](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.html%23systemd.show_status=).

Regarding the messages by `systemctl` (`service` is just a wrapper) — it shows no output in case of successful operation, which is how traditional command-line tools operate.

If a failure occurs during service startup *(NB: this does not include "shortly after startup"!)*, a message is shown, describing the failure briefly and suggesting to view the logs or to issue a separate `systemctl status` request. The failure is also indicated by a non-zero exit code.

These are all just building blocks, so you may write a simple shell function (putting it in your `~/.bashrc` or equivalent) if you prefer more verbosity. For example, in bash syntax:

```
function sctl() {
    local ACTION="$1"
    shift
    systemctl "$ACTION" "$@" || systemctl status "$@"
}
```

Comment: How I edit the "kernel cmdline"?

Comment: @rpayanm: Refer to the documentation of your distro and/or your bootloader. This is out of scope of this particular question.